# Writing code in GAP

Tags: abelian-groups, gcd-and-lcm, cyclic-groups, gap

I want to write some GAP code that prints finite abelian groups that are the direct product of two cyclic groups. However, I want the order of the cyclic groups to have the condition that the gcd(,6)=1, where  is the order of the cyclic groups and is greater than 1.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
n:=10;m:=10; #bounds on the sizes of the cyclic groups
for i in [1..n] do
    if GCD_INT(i,6)=1 then
        for j in [i..m] do
            if GCD_INT(j,6)=1 then
                Print(IdGroup(DirectProduct(CyclicGroup(i),CyclicGroup(j))));
            fi;
        od;
    fi;
 od;
```

It prints the group id from the library  [SmallGrp](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/SmallGrp-1.4.1/doc/manual.pdf), see also the function *StructureDescription(G);*

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: was it the answer to your question?

Comment: Yes thanks you.

Comment: @ChrisG if this answers your question, you are welcome to consider accepting it, and possibly upvoting it as well!